# prerequisites always install. even when not necessary

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I am deploying a .NET application with .NET Framework 3.5 client as prerequisites.

When the setup.exe runs in a machine with the prerequisites satisfied installed the bootstrapper install them again.

**Is this a known issue? and what's the correct way to solve it?**

I've tried adding this lines to the Bootstrapper Package, but it didn't change anything.

```
    <!-- This indicates .NET Framework Full is already installed -->
    <BypassIf Property="DotNet35SP" Compare="ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="1"/>

    <!-- This indicates .NET Framework Full is already installed -->
    <BypassIf Property="DotNet40Full_TargetVersion" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="4.0.30129"/>

    <!-- This indicates .NET Framework is already installed -->
    <BypassIf Property="DotNet40Client_TargetVersion" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="4.0.30129"/>
```

Comment: VS should **never** be a prerequisite. If you're installing VS on a user computer, **you're doing it wrong.**

Comment: Not just wrong, but very very wrong. What's exactly do you need? Just downloading & installing the .NET framework (for your favourite version) is all that's required.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not installing "VS 2010 C# express redistributable". I copied that part of the question from an older post, and forgot to erase that part. I've edited the question.